# How to convert form control values to object in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, http

I have an endpoint which works only when I pass raw json when I call it , for example the raw json is , but the data on my frontend is coming from form data and the api does not accept it

[image]
{
"accountId": 4,
"emailAddress": "wigin36937@ovooovo.com",
"key": "PLFFNSWFH"
}

But the api does not accept form data , so directly passing to the post request my this.verificationForm.value wont be accept and would result to error 400, what I want is how can I convert the data from verificationForm into an object like on the example above.

How do we get all the values from form data and convert it to an object before we pass it to the
validateConfirmationCode param. Thanks

```
verificationForm = this.fb.group({
    key : [null, Validators.required],
  },{
    updateOn:'submit'
  })
```

#Code

```
 onSubmit = (transaction: string): void => {
    if (transaction == 'Verification') {
      this.verificationForm.addControl("key", new FormControl(this.code))
      this.verificationForm.addControl("accountId", new FormControl(this.accountId))
      this.verificationForm.addControl("emailAddress", new FormControl(this.email))
      this.isInProgress = true;
      this._userProfileService.validateConfirmationCode(this.verificationForm.value)
        .pipe(
          finalize(() => this.isInProgress = false),
        ).subscribe({
          next: (res) => {
            if (res.isSuccess) {
              this._notificationService.showSuccess('Success');
            }
          },
          error: err => this._notificationService.showError(err),
          complete: noop
        });
```

#code2

```
  validateConfirmationCode(data: DTO): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpRequestService.post<any>(`${apiBaseUrl}/code`, data);
  }
```

Comment: isn't console.log(this.verificationForm.value) logs what you expect? I mean the form value returns an object which is what you are using in raw json.

Comment: this is the result of the console log of verificationForm https://imgur.com/a/nyN33jd but it is error 400 but when I try the endpoint on postman like on the example above it works fine and successful

Comment: If it's working in postman but not in the app, maybe you're missing some headers, or the data is in fact not the same as what's being pasted into Postman?

Comment: I believe this is not related to your data as it looks goof. Check your request headers. I see that you have set headers in your postman, are those headers part of request when calling the API from app?

Comment: the headers are correct , the response of the api when I test today is Http failure response for https://localhost:5000/api/userprofile/code: 400 OK

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface ICode :

```
export interface ICode {
    accountId: number;
    emailAddress: string;
    key: string;  
}
```

In the TS file you need to create an Object :

```
code = new Object() as ICode;
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c4vxwd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)